# Oracle APEX - How to use page items as bind variables to substitute column names and table names in SQL

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex

Basically I have a region (can be classic report, or any other types), which content is sourced from a SQL where column names and table names are page items that can be changed, like below

```
select :p1_column1, :p1_column2 from :p1_table;
```

I understand  this is not a good practice, but is this doable? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of binds, they become substitutions, ie

```
select &P1_COLUMN1., &P2_COLUMN1., etc
```

but yeah, in terms of bad practice, you're probably going to get hacked and lose all of your data.

Cest la vie :-)

Comment: Just adding to Connor's answer... If you'd like to protect yourself against SQL injection, use the DBMS_ASSERT package. https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2 Exactly how you use the package will depend on a number of things, such as how you're transferring the value of the items to session state (Ajax vs full page submit).